soy nuevo progamando y tengo un problemas con mi boton de pausa en mi proyecto mp3 de js y css
aquí esta el problema específicamente la función de "clic" reproducir pausar
a la hora de darle al botón de pausa la función no hace efecto
.png


Se armó una ensalada de código ahí. Una función lleva a otra función y al final no hace nada

Hola Angel, bienvenido, primero, evitate problemas, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen y agrega tu código como texto, segundo, podrías explicar que significa no hace efecto .png, yo no logro entender a que te refieres.por otro lado, tu función ReproducirPausa debería tener algo como:  if( reproduciendo ) cancion.pause(); else cancion.play();

Claramente la función ReproducirPausar no pausa el audio porque todo lo que hace es llamar la función reproducirCancion.
Para pausar el audio tenés que llamar la función pause. La función play reproduce el video desde donde se quedó.
